# How to use ACLs to facilitate multi-user conda system

Tags: linux, permissions, acl, conda

I'm trying to figure out a way to set up a multi-user conda system in which

- There exists a `conda` group
- Users can be added to the `conda` group
- Users can create shared environments and install packages in the central conda location

The problem is that by default, when a user alters the conda "world," the new additions belong to that users group.

I would like to use ACLs to set the default group.

I set the sticky bit so that files will default to parent permissions, and confirmed this with

```
(base) user2@balterbox:/home/conda/conda$ groups
user2 conda
(base) user2@balterbox:/home/conda/conda$ mkdir test
(base) user2@balterbox:/home/conda/conda$ ll test
total 8
drwxrwsr-x+  2 user2  conda 4096 Feb  6 20:43 ./
drwxrwsr-x+ 14 balter conda 4096 Feb  6 20:43 ../
```

I also applied the following ACLs:

```
(base) user2@balterbox:/home/conda$ getfacl conda
# file: conda
# owner: balter
# group: conda
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:conda:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

However, `user2` still cannot create a new environment:

```
(base) user2@balterbox:/home/conda$ conda create -n env2
Solving environment: done

NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
  path: /home/conda/conda/pkgs/cache/2ce54b42.json
  uid: 1002
  gid: 1002

If you feel that permissions on this path are set incorrectly, you can manually
change them by executing

  $ sudo chown 1002:1002 /home/conda/conda/pkgs/cache/2ce54b42.json

In general, it's not advisable to use 'sudo conda'.


balter@balterbox:/home/conda$ ls -al /home/conda/conda/pkgs/cache/2ce54b42.json
-rwxrwxr-x 1 balter conda 2990059 Feb  6 20:55 /home/conda/conda/pkgs/cache/2ce54b42.json
```

How do I tweak the ACLs and permissions to allow this?

Comment: @jww I appreciate the community management effort. However, ACLs ARE a programming issue. It's linux programming. For instance, I use the commands `setfacl`, `chmod`, etc. Also, if you search stackoverflow for questions relating to ACLs, you will find that they stream in by the hour. Perhaps one could make the case for using serverfault or superuser, but this seems appropriate. Also, it is impossible to present a MCV here because my test required setting up a VM, creating three users, and installing conda.

Comment: What are the permissions on the path shown in the error message?

Comment: @darthbith Thanks for catching that. I added the info.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar problem until I found this [great answer](https://serverfault.com/a/778044).
In short, you need to add both past and future writing permissions for the 'conda' group to the conda installation folder.
To do it with access control list (ACL):

```
sudo setfacl -Rm d:g:conda:rwX,g:conda:rwX /home/conda/conda
```

In more details, the `-Rm` specifies that these flags are **m**odified **R**ecursively for all subfolders of `/home/conda/conda`.
The first argument `d:g:conda:rwX` will add reading, writing and execution permission (capital `X` flag will apply it only to files/folders that are already e**x**ecutables) to members of the 'conda' **g**roup (specified by `g:conda`) for any **future** files and subfolders (specified by the `d` at the beginning, for **d**efault), whereas the second argument `g:conda:rwX`, will add these permissions to current files and folders.

You can also add `d:g:conda:rwX,g:conda:rwX,d:o::rX,o::rX` to make sure that **o**ther users (not from the `conda` group) could read and execute from that folder and use the environments (though that should be the default).

More information on `getfacl` and `setfacl` commands can be found [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/usetfacl.htm).